# Завершить рамку

Tags: python

Надо завершить рамку слева/справа. На ввод пуступает число(а) и должно получится Что то в этом духе. Между первой цифрой и левой рамкой нет пробела и с последней цифрой тоже самое.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    a=[int(i) for i in list(input())]
    d = {0: (' -- ', '|  |', '|  |', '    ', '|  |', '|  |', ' -- '),
         1: ('    ', '   |', '   |', '    ', '   |', '   |', '    '),
         2: (' -- ', '   |', '   |', ' -- ', '|   ', '|   ', ' -- '),
         3: (' -- ', '   |', '   |', ' -- ', '   |', '   |', ' -- '),
         4: ('    ', '|  |', '|  |', ' -- ', '   |', '   |', '    '),
         5: (' -- ', '|   ', '|   ', ' -- ', '   |', '   |', ' -- '),
         6: (' -- ', '|   ', '|   ', ' -- ', '|  |', '|  |', ' -- '),
         7: (' -- ', '   |', '   |', '    ', '   |', '   |', '    '),
         8: (' -- ', '|  |', '|  |', ' -- ', '|  |', '|  |', ' -- '),
         9: (' -- ', '|  |', '|  |', ' -- ', '   |', '   |', ' -- ')}
    print('x'+(5*(len(a))-1)*'-'+'x')
    for j in range(7):
        for i in a:
            print(d[i][j],end=" ")
        print()
    print('x'+(5*(len(a))-1)*'-'+'x')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так можно:

```
print('x' + (5*len(a)-1)*'-' + 'x')
for j in range(7):
    print('|', end='')
    print(' '.join(d[i][j] for i in a), end='')
    print('|')
print('x' + (5*len(a)-1)*'-' + 'x')
```

Немного ужимаем:

```
print('x' + (5*len(a)-1)*'-' + 'x')
for j in range(7):
    print('|' + ' '.join(d[i][j] for i in a) + '|')
print('x' + (5*len(a)-1)*'-' + 'x')
```

И еще чутка:

```
print('x' + (5*len(a)-1)*'-' + 'x')
print(*('|' + ' '.join(d[i][j] for i in a) + '|' for j in range(7)), sep='\n')
print('x' + (5*len(a)-1)*'-' + 'x')
```

Советы:

1. Вынести `'x' + (5*len(a)-1)*'-' + 'x'` в переменную: `border = 'x' + (5*len(a)-1)*'-' + 'x'`
2. Создать список `a` (переименовать бы его, конечно) лучше так: `a = list(map(int, input()))` или, если сильно нужны списковые выражения, так: `a = [int(i) for i in input()]`

"Однострочник":

```
border = 'x' + (5*len(a)-1)*'-' + 'x'
print(border, *('|' + ' '.join(d[i][j] for i in a) + '|' for j in range(7)), border, sep='\n')
```

Или можно так:

```
border = ('-'*(5*len(a)-1)).join('xx') + '\n'
print(''.join('|' + ' '.join(d[i][j] for i in a) + '|\n' for j in range(7)).join((border, border)))
```

Comment: Спасибо, пойду красоту наводить=)

Answer (score 0):

```
   for j in range(7):
        print('X' if j in [0,6] else '|',end=" ")
        for i in a:
            print(d[i][j],end=" ")
        print('X' if j in [0,6] else '|')
```

Comment: у вас верхние и нижние "палочки" цифр сливаются с верхней и нижней рамкой, соответственно.

Comment: `Надо завершить рамку слева/справа. `Больше не делал и даже не проверял что там с нижней рамкой